# Making improvements to code

Tags: magento

I have been working on a magento module for sometime now (not because it is a large module, its my first and I really struggled with it). I now have it working, which I was really pleased with at first, but now I would like to improve it by increasing the reusability of the code.

While making my module I have looked at other modules to learn from them and have seen that many actions are only a line or two and I have tried keeping in with the skinny controller approach but failed, my example is as follows:

I have a function that get a users details that they have inputted into a custom form

```
protected function _setPostData()
{        
    $this->_salutation = $this->getRequest()->getPost('salutation');
    $this->_f_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('f_name');
    $this->_l_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('l_name');
    $this->_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
    $this->_emailAddressCheck = $this->getRequest()->getPost('emailAddressCheck');
    $this->_gender = $this->getRequest()->getPost('gender');
    $this->_country = $this->getRequest()->getPost('country');
    $this->_pref_lang = $this->getRequest()->getPost('pref_lang');        
}
```

I feel that this is not the correct way to do it and that there is a better way of achieving the same goal, as you can see this function gets the posts data and assigns it to attributes that i've set at the start of the class. I have several other examples that are very similar to the above and if someone could please offer some guidance on this one I am sure I will be able to work out the others

This example is held within the index action, should I put it in a helper as once it created correctly i am sure there will be a few occasions that I will be able to use it again?

Comment: Post here instead: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you should put all the post data on an array and use it from there

```
$dataArray=$this->getRequest()->getPost();  

$this->_salutation = $dataArray['salutation'];
$this->_f_name = $dataArray['f_name'];
$this->_l_name = $dataArray['l_name'];
```

Comment: So the only thing I have done wrong with this is not add it to an array? How is it that so many of Magentos functions have so few lines?

Comment: you're probably referring to things like $model->setData($dataArray), but those types of lines are using the magento Model structure where you can have a table with the names of those variables (like salutation, f_name, etc), you can then load the table through a model and just do $model->setData($dataArray)